# IF Statement issue on Windows batchfile

Tags: windows, if-statement

The windows batch file code below is aiming to get the figure out if a certain process is running. If it is running it should, execute a .exe then wait 7 seconds, and finally return to the beginning. If the process is not running, the it should wait 30 seconds and then check again. The issue I'm having is executing anything after the IF statement. The program seems to stop after if the IF statement is not true. Thus, the other portion of the code is never executed. I think it might be a syntax error, but I cannot find it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
set %testx%="0"
:susbegin
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%F in ('tasklist /fo CSV /fi "Imagename eq Bentley.lictransmit.exe" /nh') do set testx=%%F

if %testx%=="Bentley.lictransmit.exe" goto susexe

ping 192.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 30000 > nul 
goto susbegin

:susexe 
pssuspend -r Bentley.lictransmit.exe 
ping 192.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 7000 > nul 
set %testx%="0" 
goto susbegin 
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around `%testx%`, like this:

```
if "%testx%"=="Bentley.lictransmit.exe" goto susexe
```

Also, at the beginning and end you should *not* have quotes around it when you set it.

This is wrong:

```
set %testx%="0"
```

It should be:

```
set testx="0"
```